# Using PrinterWriter with a String ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, printwriter

Here is the prompt I was given to work with (I got the expected result by replacing the line "`File input = new File(args[0]);`" with "`File input = new File("data.txt");`" but I was wondering if this could be done somehow using a command line):
 The following program has the String array-list object. Compute the total value
from the input file, after that print out the total value into a new file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
class FileIOArrayList {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
 {

 List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

File input = new File(args[0]);
 Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(input);
 while (myScanner.hasNextInt()){
      data.add(myScanner.nextInt());
      }

      PrintWriter myWriter = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

       for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
      {
      myWriter.println(data.get(i));
      }
      myWriter.close();

    }
   }
```

====Output Example=======

```
32
54
76
90
10
300
543
179
4
2
5
Total sum = 1295
```

Comment: Please clarify the statement "could be done somehow using a command line"

Comment: My teacher has been using lines such as:  java FileIOArrayList 1.  but this gets a out of bounds error on the array, is there a way to call the file data.txt from terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this through the command line, you must specify command-line arguments. You can pass in the name of the file as a command-line argument by placing it after the class name like so:

```
java FileIOArrayList data.txt
```

Check out the tutorial on [Command Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).